# How to tell if it is knockout.js that is disabling element and not something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, google-chrome-devtools

I have a page that uses Jquery Mobile UI pagination, where pagination navigation blocking might be controlled by multiple sources (I am not 100% sure if that's true but please hear me out). There is viewmodel `isValid()` method and if model is not valid knockout.js `enable` binding is supposed to disable navigation controls. What I am seeing is that `isValid()` returns `true` but control remains disabled.
**How can I tell if it's knockout binding that is ignoring isValid function change?** It might be that there is another mechanism out there that disables button, but before I go hunting for it I would like to make sure that knockout.js is functional.
In screenshot below I have printed out relevant values.

[image]

Comment: If you know where your viewmodel is registered in the global name space (ie. window.myViewModel) you could always toggle the observable from the console to see if it re-enables it

Comment: As a general hint: You are not supposed to put any code in your bindings (the fact that you *can* does not mean you *should*). And certainly not entire functions. Use computed observables and custom bindings, your view should contain no business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that the `enable` binding-handler does it toggling the `disabled` **property** of the element as well as removing the `disabled` **attribute** (when enabled evaluated to true).

The easiest way for you to see if it does something (in your Inspector) is to add the `disabled` attribute and watch it changing:

```
<a disabled="disabled" data-role="button" data-bind="...">
    ....
</a>
```

See [KO source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/enableDisable.js).

Comment: It does remove it, so I guess knockout is working fine. Thanks.